# AWS S3 SDK v2 for iOS - Download an image file to UIImage

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Seems this should be relatively simple. I'm using the AWS SDK (v2) for iOS and I'm trying to download a .png file and display it to the screen in a UIImage. Everything actually works! Just very strangely...

Here is my code:

```
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:@"MY_ACCESS_KEY" secretKey:@"MY_SECRET_KEY"];
    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

    AWSS3 *transferManager = [[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
    AWSS3GetObjectRequest *getImageRequest = [AWSS3GetObjectRequest new];
    getImageRequest.bucket = @"MY_BUCKET";
    getImageRequest.key = @"MY_KEY";

    [[transferManager getObject:getImageRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        if(task.error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",task.error);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Got image");
            NSData *data = [task.result body];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            myImageView.image = image;
        }
        return nil;
    }];
```

When this code gets executed, the continueWithBlock gets executed, there is no task error, so **Got image** is logged. And this happens fairly quickly. However, it's not until about 10 seconds later that the UIImageView updates on the screen. I even ran through the debugger to see if any of the lines following the `NSLog(@"Got image");` line were taking long and they weren't. They were all executing very quickly but then the UIImageView would not be updated on the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are updating UI component from a background thread. The `continueWithBlock:` block is executed in the background thread, and it is causing the aforementioned behavior. You have two options:

1. Use Grand Central Dispatch in the block and run it on the main thread:

   ```
   ...
   NSURL *fileURL = [task.result body];
   NSData *data = // convert fileURL to data
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
       myImageView.image = image;
   });
   ...
   ```
2. Use `mainThreadExecutor` to run the block on the main thread:

   ```
   [[transferManager getObject:getImageRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                           withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
   ...
   ```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm ;) Always good to hear from the creator of the library you're struggling with.

Comment: BTW now I notice it actually takes a couple seconds to download even a small image, but I think that will be resolved if I take advantage of CloudFront

Comment: [task.result body] is an instance of NSURL, not NSData. Test on aws-ios-sdk-2.1.2