# Display UIImageView using Swift from AWS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to render an image in UIImageView using Swift. The source object is located in an AWS S3 bucket. I could not find any example code on Google. So I tried to translate the code given in this link [[AWS S3 SDK v2 for iOS - Download an image file to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920026/aws-s3-sdk-v2-for-ios-download-an-image-file-to-uiimage]) from Obj-C to Swift, but failed. I'm a beginner in iOS.

```
        let accessKey = "ACCESS_CODE";
        let secretKey = "SECRET_KEY";
        // let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithAccessKey(accessKey, secretKey: secretKey) 
        // ^ Xcode says - credentialsWithAccessKey is deprecated, use initWithAccessKey 
        let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.initWithAccessKey(accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
        // ^ Xcode says - AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.Type does not have a member named ‘initWithAccessKey’
```

I could be doing very many things wrong here, even silly mistakes. The best help would be to point to some example code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried like this

```
var credentialsProvider: AWSStaticCredentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithAccessKey("MY_ACCESS_KEY", secretKey: "MY_SECRET_KEY")
var configuration: AWSServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration.configurationWithRegion(AWSRegionUSWest1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
var transferManager: AWSS3 = AWSS3(configuration: configuration)
var getImageRequest: AWSS3GetObjectRequest = AWSS3GetObjectRequest.new()
getImageRequest.bucket = "MY_BUCKET"
getImageRequest.key = "MY_KEY"
transferManager.getObject(getImageRequest).continueWithExecutor(BFExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: {(task: BFTask) -> id in    if task.error {
        NSLog("Error: %@", task.error)
    }
    else {
        NSLog("Got image")
        var data: NSData = task.result.body()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {    
        var image: UIImage = UIImage.imageWithData(data)
        myImageView.image = image

        })
```

Comment: Thank you Rajatp. This is much better. Though 2 lines of code are giving errors. The line that says ‘var transferManager: AWSS3 = AWSS3(configuration: configuration)’ is reporting: ‘init(configuration) is unavailable: Use ‘+ registerS3WithConfiguration:forKey:’ and ‘+ S3ForKey:’ instead. The second error is on the line saying: “transferManager.getObject...”. Here “Use of undeclared type ‘id’: Did you mean to use ‘AnyObject’?”. For first error, I tried using registerS3… and then S3ForKey, but the S3ForKey statement Xcode reports “Extra argument ‘forKey’ in call.

Comment: check this link http://sledgedev.com/aws-s3-image-upload-using-aws-sdk-for-ios-v2/

Comment: @dato I dropped the Swift idea and eventually used ObjC. Want me post the ObjC code?

Comment: @ShirishHirekodi actually I successfully show the image.

Comment: @dato may be you should post it as an answer here for benefit of others

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom class to download image. It worked for me.

```
class AWSImageDownloader {

    init(AccessKey accessKey:String, SecretKey secretKey:String, andRegion region:AWSRegionType = .USEast1) {

        let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
        guard let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: region, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider) else {
            debugPrint("Failed to configure")
            return
        }

        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    }

    func downloadImage(Name imageName:String, fromBucket bucketName:String, onDownload successCallback:@escaping AWSImageDownloadSuccess, andOnError errorCallback:@escaping AWSImageDownloadError){

        let transferManager     = AWSS3.default()
        let getImageRequest     = AWSS3GetObjectRequest()
        getImageRequest?.bucket = bucketName
        getImageRequest?.key    = imageName
        transferManager.getObject(getImageRequest!).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread()) { (anandt) -> Void in
            if anandt.error == nil {
                if let imageData = anandt.result?.body as? Data, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                    successCallback(image)
                } else {
                    errorCallback("Download failed")
                }
            } else {

                let error = "Error \(anandt.error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown by dev")"
                errorCallback(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```